# Can I set saturation and luminosity while preserving hue in imagemagick?

Tags: colors, imagemagick

I'm tring to set the saturation and luminosity channels to a fixed value (100% saturation, 75% luinosity) on an image.

Following [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate) I thought I'd use a evaluate - and this works ok:

```
convert input.png -colorspace HSL \
          -channel B -evaluate multiply 0.80 \
          -channel G -evaluate multiply 1.20 \
          output.png
```

but doing this:

```
convert input.png -colorspace HSL \
         -channel G -evaluate set 100 \ 
         -channel B -evaluate set 50 \
          output.png
```

results in a black image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your setting the channel data to a specific quantum value. A quantum value of 100 is about 1.5% if your working with ImageMagick Q16.

Ensure that the value ends with '%'

```
convert input.png -colorspace HSL \
         -channel G -evaluate set 100% \ 
         -channel B -evaluate set 50% \
         output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

`@emcconville` is correct. But I will add one more thing. Perhaps you also want to convert back to sRGB colorspace. So

```
convert lena.png -colorspace HSL \
-channel G -evaluate set 100% +channel \
-channel B -evaluate set 50% +channel \
-colorspace sRGB output2.png
```